# Change customer's name in app store

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I uploaded my app in hurry, and somehow I messed up and chosen wrong name for our customer.
Is there any quick way to change this string (in the red circle in my pic) from my iTunes account? 
[image]

I've been searching for some time now, but without any success.

Edit: My app is approved and is on appstore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact apple support, see
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1657353?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: So that means, that if I'm indie developer, developing for alot of companies, I have to ask apple to change it every time? I'm little bit confused, pardon me :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean developing for a lot of companies? Usually those you develop for should have their own apple account so that their name is listed correctly on the app store. If you add several apps for your account they will all be listed with the current company name of your account.

Comment: Ok Architect, thank you for your time... Upvoted/accepted